# are all the examples of cross product code on the internet wrong, or am I wrong?

Tags: java, c, math, vector, vectormath

Background: I'm writing some code in fanuc macro b for machining centers with touch probes, but I guess that's kindof irrelevent... anyways, I'm currently writing a little program to take 3 touches on a surface and output a unit normal vector.

Before I started, I did some searching for examples of vector cross products in other programming languages, and of course, I found lots of them. the thing I'm confused about is that none of the examples I found negate the y (or j) term.. this what I found in various forms across the web:

x = Ay * Bz - By * Az

y = Az * Bx - Bz * Ax

z = Ax * By - Bx * Ay

am I missing something? I thought it should look like this:

x = Ay * Bz - By * Az

y = -1 * (Az * Bx - Bz * Ax)

z = Ax * By - Bx * Ay

I mean I feel like I have to be wrong because the entire internet is rarely wrong.. but on paper it only works out when I do it my way...

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"on paper it only works out when I do it my way"*? The usual way to calculate it is like the first version, how did you arrive at the second?

Comment: it depends on whether you're using a right-handed or left-handed coordinate system.

Comment: By the way, the first form is not just mentioned on the web, it's also in a lot of mathematics and physics books

Comment: thanks guys, the answer below helped me understand. I knew I was wrong here, but couldn't see the reversal between the standard formula and the cofactor method. not sure if I can or should delete this post or if it should remain for shame purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think that the problem is the way you read the examples. Let us look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). I find:

```
s1 = a2*b3 - a3*b2
s2 = a3*b1 - a1*b3
s3 = a1*b2 - a2*b2
```

You just write the second line: `s2 = -1 * (a1*b3 - a3*b1)` which is exactly the same thing...